# facebook API error : Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

guys i'm getting this error

Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating access token. thrown in /home/techtud1/public_html/library/facebook.php on line 543

i'm a newbie to facebook development but i'm using the exact steps of this tutorial 
http://www.joeyrivera.com/2010/facebook-graph-api-app-easy-w-php-sdk/ 
when i tried to get the information of the user i got it once , but when i tried to do it again i got this error . and whatever i'm doing , i'm getting this error as a result

HELP PZ

Comment: I need help with this issue as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is FBML, header() doesnt work. You need to use fb:redirect

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/redirect/

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and what solved it in my case was deleting the App from the FB User's profile and adding it again creating a new ACCESS_TOKEN. I do not know why, but this solved by problem.

Comment: Did you possibly request more permissions?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start learning from the official facebook php-sdk [`example.php`](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php).

I found it a lot easier to kick-off and straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Check This

```
$app_id         = "YOUR_APP_ID";
$app_sec        = "APP_SEC";
$canvas_page    = "APP_CANVAS_PAGE_URL";
$scope          = "&scope=user_photos,email,publish_stream";                
$auth_url       = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) . $scope; 

$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];   
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode(".", $signed_request, 2); 
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, "-_", "+/")), true); 
if (empty($data["user_id"])) 
{
    echo("");
} 
$access_token   = $data["oauth_token"]; 
$user_id        = $data["user_id"]; 
$user           = json_decode( file_get_contents( "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" . $access_token ) ); 

function get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $application_secret)
{ 
    $args = array();
    parse_str(trim($COOKIE["fbs" . $app_id], "\""), $args); 
    ksort($args);
    $payload = ""; 
    foreach ($args as $key => $value) { 
        if ($key != "sig") 
        { 
            $payload .= $key . "=" . $value; 
        }
    } 
    if (md5($payload . $application_secret) != $args["sig"]) 
    {
        return null; 
    } 
    return $args; 
} 

$cookie = get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $app_sec);
```