# posting photo to facebook raises exception

Tags: php, facebook

i wrote a function to post a photo to a users wall and it raises the following exception

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: A user access token is required to request this resource. thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\upd8r\application\helpers\base_facebook.php on line 1039
```

this is my code- what am i missing?

```
function facebook_img_post($fb_id,$data){


        $this->load->helper('facebook');

        $this->load->model('mmaster');
        $globalSettings = $this->mmaster->getGlobalSettings('1');

        // Create our Application instance.
        $this->facebook = new Facebook(array(
          'appId'  => $globalSettings['facebook_id'],
          'secret' => $globalSettings['facebook_secret'],
          'cookie' => false
        ));

        $this->facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);


        $this->facebook->api("/".$fb_id."/photos",'post', array(
                'message'=> $data['message'],
                'source' => $data['source']
            )
        );





        //new fb post

    }
```

**update**

this is the link the user registered with showing all the permissions requested

```
$data['loginUrl']   =   $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'read_stream,publish_stream,status_update,offline_access'))
```

**update 2**

I swapped the api out and tried it with curl to have more control and apparently i need a user access token- even though i was retrieving and using an application access token- apparently there are two different ones.

Comment: Similar question to this one: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662118/facebook-api-error-uncaught-oauthexception-error-validating-access-token][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662118/facebook-api-error-uncaught-oauthexception-error-validating-access-token

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the user grant you `publish_stream` and `manage_page` permissions also to do this when you get the loginURL, e.g.

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
    array(
        'scope' =>'user_status,user_photos,status_update,manage_pages,publish_stream,offline_access',
        'redirect_uri'  => $fbconfig['baseurl']
        )
);
```

Here's some more info:
FB permissions: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Tutorial for connecting to FB including asking for permissions: http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-3-0-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Comment: i have done this already. the user has granted permission and offline_access as well

Comment: Did you ask for publish_stream permissions as well as offline_access?

Comment: I have edited the code to add the offline_access permissions to show where you need to request the publish_stream permission.

Comment: i have included how i request permissions- its an exisitng application that already has stream posts posting

Comment: Its quite a while since I've had to do this, so I've updated my post with all the permissions I requested in my app... I think the other one you need is manage_pages, but I've included them all just in case.

Answer (score 1):

you need to request an access token with `publish_stream` permission

check out this links:

- [Permission on FB](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)
- [Photo graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/)

**UPDATE**

after creating an instance for `new Facebook` you have to redirect to the FB for user authentication:

```
$loginUrl = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'publish_stream, offline_access'));
echo '<script>top.location.href="'.$loginUrl.'"</script>';
```

**second update**

if you're doing all in this way and the problem still exists, then maybe you're passing the image data to curl incorrectly. You must prepend image path with `@` to inform CURL that it must send the image as multipart data.

Comment: sorry for posting the same multiple time, I had a connection issue

Comment: i have included how i request permissions- its an exisitng application that already has stream posts posting

Comment: then there could be other reason, last time I had the same issue. As I understand $data['source'] contains the path to the image, right? Do you prepend the path with `@` symbol?

Comment: it contains the filesystem path eg.. @C:\xampp\htdocs\upd8r\/img_uploads/webcam/finish.png

Comment: have you set the `fileUpload` property of fb connector class to true? like this:

`$config = array ('appId' => FB_APPID, 'secret' => FB_SECRET, 'fileUpload' => true);`
`$fb = new Facebook($config);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5842/discussion-between-haynar-and-chris-mccabe)